# interpret Javascript from $.get

Tags: javascript, getjson

I want to use someting like `$.get` to retrieve data from an URL. 
If this data is a Javascript command like `alert();`, can I run it ?

Or do I have to use something else?

Comment: [$.getScript](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/) is what you're looking for.

Comment: Oh yeah thanks, you can post it as an asnwer i'll accept it thanks :)